# Completar números com Javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu estou preso em uma questão aqui e preciso de uma ajuda.

Preciso fazer um autocomplete em um input de boleto bancario.

**Exemplo:**

12345.56789.00085.111111.11111.234566.6.**00000000000000**

Nesse ultimo campo, caso o usuário não digite nada ele teria que autocompletar com "0".

***Se caso fosse nesse exemplo:***

12345.56789.00085.111111.11111.234566.6.**123**

**O input teria que retornar:**

12345.56789.00085.111111.11111.234566.6.**12300000000000**

Sempre autocompletando com zeros a direita.

Como eu consigo fazer isso em javascript?

Comment: Poste parte do seu código para que possamos te auxiliar melhor.

Comment: Tem um padrão isso ai? Quando numeros zero a direita? Os pontos continuam como pontos? Eu acho que isso ai vai precisar de uma mascara, nem `.repeat(14-num.length)` e nem `.padEnd(54, "0")` vão resolver o seu problema de verdade (eu acho, não tenho certeza). Por favor edite a pergunta e deixe mais claro estes pontos.

Comment: No caso no meu código já tem essa regra de alocar os "." para separar e sim é no ultimo campo, no caso 14 digitos. O problema que os usuarios as vezes esquecem de colocar o número zero, invalidando o boleto. Então é pra autocompletar até chegar a quantidade necessária de caractere que é de: 54

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) do javascript para repetir o "0" n vezes de acordo com o tamanho da string.
Pelo que percebi no seu exemplo, deve ter um tamanho de 14 (a última parte), então:

```js
var num = "123";
console.log(num + "0".repeat(14-num.length));
```

Answer (score 1):

A ação de completar com um determinado caratere até fazer um tamanho costuma se chamar de *pad*. O javascript já tem funções para fazer *pad* tanto à esquerda como à direita, sendo elas o [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) e [`padEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) respetivamente.

No seu caso utilizando o `padEnd` tem o efeito pretendido:

```js
let boleto = "12345.56789.00085.111111.11111.234566.6.123";
let boletoCompletado = boleto.padEnd(54, "0");
console.log(boletoCompletado);
```

O primeiro parâmetro do `padEnd`, os `54`, indicam a quantidade de careteres que deve passar a ter, e o segundo parâmetro indica caratere a colocar até fazer o tamanho desejado.

Caso precise de suportar navegadores muito antigos onde estas duas funções possam não existir, pode se servir do polyfill mencionado nas páginas de documentação.

Answer (score 0):

Simplesmente faça o .length da string, e no fim se for inferior ao número pretendido, por exemplo:

```
if(input.length < 54)
```

faz += o número de 0s que pode ser feito com um ciclo for de 54 - input.length (isto se for 54 o número total)

Um exemplo pederia ser: (código pode não compilar, não estou a testar)

```
var textoInput = "";
(...)
if(textoInput.length < 54) {
   var zeros = "";
   for(int i = 0; i < (54 - TextoInpit.length); i++) {
       zeros += "0";
   }
   textoInput += zeros;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer algo parecido com isso, mas precisa calcular a quantidade que deseja por de zeros, e a quantidade que deseja limitar:

```
var numero="12345.56789.00085.111111.11111.234566.6.123", numero_repeticoes = numero.length, numero_remocoes = numero.length * 2;

var content = "0".repeat(numero_repeticoes).padStart(numero_remocoes, numero); (content).substring(54, -54);
```

Ou simplificar assim:

```
numero.padEnd(58, "0");
```

O que realmente não sei é a quantidade que você deseja de zeros, então você deve estabelecer um limitador de tamanho (limite da sua string)...